# Google Cloud Print service for Windows Server

Tags: google-chrome, printing, windows-server, google-cloud-print

Currently I have my Android tablet set up to print through Chrome's Cloud Print service on my PC. This works, but requires that my PC be on whenever I want to print. Since the point of having the tablet is to be able to use network services when I'm away my PC is usually off when I'm not using it.

I'd like to set up Cloud Print on my Windows server (which *is* always on) and configure my tablet to use a printer there instead. (As it happens, it's the same printer, but that's by-the-by). Google have a Windows service I could use, but it requires that I install Chrome on my server, which I don't want to do if I can avoid it.

So my question is: is there a non-Chrome Windows service I can use to share my printer through GCP?

I did find one for Linux which I could use (I have a Fedora server too), but Linux print drivers for my printer are hard to come by.

Comment: There are lots. Depending on your printer you could look at HP ePrint or Epson iPrint. Also if you go to the Play Store on your tablet and search for `print` you'll find lots of other cloud-based printing solutions.

Comment: I'm not looking to buy a new printer. HP ePrint assumes I have an HP printer with ePrint support. Epson iPrint requires an Epson printer with eMail support. The Google Play solutions all focus on printing from the device. I have that sorted - it's connecting my printer to GCP that is the problem.

Comment: Now i understand. I think it will be hard to find one. Which one did you find for linux (which will serve as gcp-server on the printer side)? I only found google cloud print drivers. Which wil print **to** a gcp.

Comment: I found some sample code on Github written in PHP. Too bad, I can't find it now to give you the link. And no - I don't want the pain of making PHP work on my Windows server - I'll install Chrome first.

Comment: ;) no Windows yet but found [this one](https://github.com/armooo/cloudprint) for sharing CUPS printers with google's cloud print (in python).

Comment: I can't get a Linux driver for my printer so any Linux based solution will be problematic.